# Ionic 3 incorrect scroll behavior

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic3

It's hard to describe this problem and I'm not sure if it's a bug or i just misunderstood some ionic layouts, also i've tested only on ios so not sure about other platforms, so here we go:

I am using ionic 3.19, ios 11.2

If content in `<ionic-content>` is bigger(vertically) than screen, then if i scroll it upwards(causing overscroll) or downwards(also causing overscroll) just the moment i stop touching it - content makes a jump to the top of the view, it's really hard to describe, here is way to reproduce: start new ionic tabs project. Add 15 or so `<ion-card>` with some text to any tab, so for instance `home.html` looks like:

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>Header</ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>Body</ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>Header</ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>Body</ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>Header</ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>Body</ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>Header</ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>Body</ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>Header</ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>Body</ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>Header</ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>Body</ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>Header</ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>Body</ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

(just to make sure content bigger than the screen), run on iphone(`ionic cordova start ios --device`), make a little scroll down, and then fast scroll up and put the finger off the screen while it's still scrolling up

Have anybody encountered this? I've been fighting this for days now, at first i thought it has something to do with my styles, but it could be reproduced with pure ionic features

I am using just the starter ionic tabs project, changed only home.html, **all scss are in the initial ionic state**

[image: Original speed gif]

Comment: I tried this in my App and I see no issues.....Are you sure you haven't modified your home.scss file.....Please check to see that your home.scss file contains nothing but   page-home {   }

Comment: if you can zip your project folder and send across to ajayreddy.4480@gmail.com then I can take a look

Comment: Please record your issue then export it to a `.gif` so we can see it

Comment: @DmytroGrynets is it possible to slow down that gif a little? Also, change the heading into heading 1, heading 2, heading 3, and so on...

Comment: Also....please add more <ion-card> div's

Comment: @AjayReddy Sure if i add more of those it gets harder to reproduce, but what if i need exactly this amount? It shouldn't behave like that upon any amount

Comment: @DmytroGrynets please add this information in **[this Github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11844)**. Seems like is still a bug in the latest version of Ionic, but maybe if we "activate" that Github issue it could be resolved in the next version.

Comment: @sebaferreras Thank you, it is exactly the same issue i'm facing, couldn't find it on ionic bug tracker, if you wish you can post your comment as answer and i'll accept it

Comment: Glad to hear that @DmytroGrynets! I'd say that it would be unfair to add that as an answer because it does not solve your question/issue. If it's ok for you, let's keep those 200 points to motivate any Ionic developer to actually fix the issue :)

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I'm struggling with same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your items with `<ion-list></ion-list>`

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        Your cards here...
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your is a unique problem.

I'm trying to generate same problem as yours but i can't.
Anyway, can you try to add this in index.html

```
  <ion-app style="z-index: 1"></ion-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me:

**Steps:**

1. ionic cordova platform add ios && ionic cordova prepare ios
2. Then find CDVWKWebViewEngine.m, inside /platforms/ios//Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/
3. Put this line of code at the bottom of the lines and save it.

```js
@implementation UIScrollView (NoBounce)
- (void)didMoveToWindow {
   [super didMoveToWindow];
   self.bounces = NO;
}
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `no-bounce` attribute to your `<ion-content>` element

```
<ion-content no-bounce padding>
   <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>Header</ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>Body</ion-card-content>
   </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please take a closer look at the problem, adding no-bounce doesn't solve it

Comment: We had the same issue on IOS, added `no-bounce` and it worked. Ionic V3.9.2. Will have a look on new project when I have a gap

Comment: @DmytroGrynets you did add the `no-bounce` to the parent view right? And not the child view which is the home tab controller view